# How to create an automated dynamic line graph in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, graph, line

I have a work problem. I have a data report with tons of information in it and I need to create 3 line graphs to represent 3 different values over time. The time is also in the report and is the same time for all of the values. I am having trouble finding a solution specific to me in forums elsewhere.

The data report varies in length, rows. What I need to do is to create the 3 line graphs and have them positioned horizontally, a few rows under the end of the report. Two of the graphs have one series each and the third has two series.

This is what the graphs need to include:

Graph 1: RPM over Time
Graph 2: Pressure over Time
Graph 3: Step burn off and Demand burn off over Time

I am just getting into VBA because of a recent position change at work and I know very little about it but I have spent a lot of time figuring out how to write other macros for the same report. Since my verbal representation of the workbook is unclear I have attached a link to a sample of the data report for viewing.

[Data Report Workbook Download](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/28487159/Work%20Example.xls)
[image: Extract from Download + Added Charts]

Here is what I have so far. It works for the first chart. Now what can I put in the code to name the chart "RPM" and to name the series "RPM"?

```
    Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim ShName As String
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow & ", E2:E" & LastRow)
        ShName = .Name

    End With
    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName
    End With
End Sub
```

I have figured out how to put the chart name in via VBA. The code now looks like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim ShName As String
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow & ", E2:E" & LastRow)
        ShName = .Name
    End With

    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "RPM"
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName
    End With

End Sub
```

I will next be working on the series title and then on to having the chart place itself under the report data. Suggestions and comments welcome.

The updated code below creates the rpm chart and the pressure chart separately. The last chart needs two series and I am working on that now.

```
Sub chts()

'RPM chart-------------------------------------
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim ShName As String
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng1 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow & ", E2:E" & LastRow)
        ShName = .Name
    End With

    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "RPM"
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng1
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName
    End With

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Name = "RPM"
    End With

' Pressure chart --------------------------------

    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim ShName2 As String
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow2 = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set Rng2 = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow2 & ", G2:G" & LastRow2)
        ShName2 = .Name
    End With

    Charts.Add
    With ActiveChart
        .ChartType = xlLine
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Text = "Pressure/psi"
        .SetSourceData Source:=Rng2
        .Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:=ShName2
    End With

    With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
        .Name = "Pressure"
    End With
End Sub
```

David, I am curious to see how your code works with my worksheet but I'm not sure how to fix the syntax error.

Comment: Not yet, I tried to piece together bits and pieces from segments I found on other sites and forums but I continuously get errors and start over.

Comment: That is what the end result should look like. If I can get the process automated that will be exactly what I need. With the exception of the last graph looking mangled. I'm sure I can straighten that out later on.

Comment: Yes, I can draw them and input the data ranges manually but I would like to have it automated and then I will assign the macro to a button like the "Trim" button I have already put in. After the button is clicked the Report sheet should like the picture above.

Comment: dont even do the data ranges  manually. You can use dynamic named ranges for that, or via VBA if you are going that route. And the Chart positioning is handled through its containing object Top and Left, easily manipulated through VBA.

Comment: @K_B I was just saying that I know how to put the graphs together manually. What I want the macro to do is to take the information and make three graphs and place them below the all of the data. I just don't know how to write the code for it. I struggled piecing together the little code that is used in my "Trim" macro.

Comment: @pnuts - It sounds like you understand what I am trying to do. I have recorded a macro of making a line graph with the time and RPM data but the code is still going to keep the data range static. As I've said before, I am very new to this. I would appreciate some assistance if possible. Eventually I would like to read through the code and understand what it is doing. It seems I bit off more than I can chew.

Comment: I suppose those things could help, but as I've mentioned before, I don't really understand the syntax or how to just write the code. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manipulate the Series title (you only have one series in each of these charts) you could do simply:

```
With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1)
    .Name = "RPM"
    '## You can further manipulate some series properties, like: '
    '.XValues = range_variable  '## you can assign a range of categorylabels here'
    '.Values = another_range_variable '## you can assign a range of Values here'
End With
```

Now, what code you have is *adding* charts to the sheet. But once they have been created, presumably you don't want to re-add a new chart, you just want to update the existing chart.

Assuming you only will have one series in each of these charts, you could do something like this to **update** the charts.

How it works is by iterating over each chart in the worksheet's chartobjects collection, and then determining what Range to use for the Series Values, based on the chart's title.

**REVISED** to account for the third chart which has 2 series.

**REVISED #2** To add series to chart if chart does not have series data.

```
Sub UpdateCharts()
Dim cObj As ChartObject
Dim cht As Chart
Dim shtName As String
Dim chtName As String
Dim xValRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set xValRange = .Range("B2:B" & LastRow)
    shtName = .Name & " "
End With


'## This sets values for Series 1 in each chart ##'
For Each cObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    Set cht = cObj.Chart
    chtName = shtName & cht.Name

    If cht.SeriesCollection.Count = 0 Then
    '## Add a dummy series which will be replaced in the code below ##'
        With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
            .Values = "{1,2,3}"
            .XValues = xValRange
        End With

    End If

    '## Assuming only one series per chart, we just reset the Values & XValues per chart ##'
    With cht.SeriesCollection(1)
    '## Assign the category/XValues ##'
       .XValues = xValRange

    '## Here, we set the range to use for Values, based on the chart name: ##'
        Select Case Replace(chtName, shtName, vbNullString)
             Case "RPM"
                  .Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 3) '## Column E is 3 offset from the xValRange in column B
             Case "Pressure/psi"
                  .Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 5) '## Column G is 5 offset from the xValRange in column B
             Case "Third Chart"
                .Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 6)   '## Column H is 6 offset from the xValRange in column B

                '## Make sure this chart has 2 series, if not, add a dummy series ##'
                If cht.SeriesCollection.Count < 2 Then
                    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                        .XValues = "{1,2,3}"
                    End With
                End If
                '## add the data for second series: ##'
                cht.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = xValRange
                cht.SeriesCollection(2).Values = xValRange.Offset(0, 8)  '## Column J is 8 offset from the xValRange in column B

             Case "Add as many of these Cases as you need"

        End Select

    End With

Next
End Sub
```

**REVISION #3** To allow for creation of charts if they do not already exist in the worksheet, add these lines to the bottom of your `DeleteRows_0_Step()` subroutine:

`Run "CreateCharts"`

`Run "UpdateCharts"`

Then, add these subroutines to the same code module:

```
Private Sub CreateCharts()

Dim chts() As Variant
Dim cObj As Shape
Dim cht As Chart
Dim chtLeft As Double, chtTop As Double, chtWidth As Double, chtHeight As Double
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim c As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastRow = ws.Range("A1", Range("A2").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

c = -1
'## Create an array of chart names in this sheet. ##'
For Each cObj In ActiveSheet.Shapes
    If cObj.HasChart Then
        ReDim Preserve chts(c)
        chts(c) = cObj.Name

        c = c + 1
    End If
Next

'## Check to see if your charts exist on the worksheet ##'
If c = -1 Then
    ReDim Preserve chts(0)
    chts(0) = ""
End If
If IsError(Application.Match("RPM", chts, False)) Then
    '## Add this chart ##'
    chtLeft = ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Left
    chtTop = ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Top + ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Height
    Set cObj = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine, chtLeft, chtTop, 355, 211)
        cObj.Name = "RPM"
        cObj.Chart.HasTitle = True
        Set cht = cObj.Chart
        cht.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "RPM"
        clearChart cht
End If


If IsError(Application.Match("Pressure/psi", chts, False)) Then
    '## Add this chart ##'
    With ws.ChartObjects("RPM")
        chtLeft = .Left + .Width + 10
        chtTop = .Top
        Set cObj = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine, chtLeft, chtTop, 355, 211)
        cObj.Name = "Pressure/psi"
        cObj.Chart.HasTitle = True
        Set cht = cObj.Chart
        cht.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Pressure/psi"
        clearChart cht
    End With
End If


If IsError(Application.Match("Third Chart", chts, False)) Then
    '## Add this chart ##'
    With ws.ChartObjects("Pressure/psi")
        chtLeft = .Left + .Width + 10
        chtTop = .Top
        Set cObj = ws.Shapes.AddChart(xlLine, chtLeft, chtTop, 355, 211)
        cObj.Name = "Third Chart"
        cObj.Chart.HasTitle = True
        Set cht = cObj.Chart
        cht.ChartTitle.Characters.Text = "Third Chart"
        clearChart cht
    End With
End If


End Sub

Private Sub clearChart(cht As Chart)
Dim srs As Series
For Each srs In cht.SeriesCollection
    If Not cht.SeriesCollection.Count = 1 Then srs.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I copied your code to see how it works on my worksheet but I keep getting a syntax error at 'Set xValRange = '. And just to inform you the last chart will actually have two series. I will continue to look through the MSDN Office Reference page.

Comment: Also please note that I am trying to put all three chart coding in one module because I plan on attaching this one macro to a button for one click ease. This is just to cut time out of creating the reports for clients and being able to do them as quickly as possible. I appreciate all of the help and input so far.

Comment: When you get the error, what is the error message and what is the value of `lastRow` variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I copied your code exactly as it is. Forgive my lack of knowledge. Am I supposed to specify the lastRow variable further? As of now I just get the message that there is a syntax error at the second instance of "Set xValRange ="

Comment: Ooops!  I see that now. Delete that line -- not sure why it's there but it shouldn't be there! Sorry! I will revise :)

Comment: Ha, it's okay! I took it out and now I get a "Compile Error: Invalid or Unqualified reference" at the line "With .SeriesCollection(1)"

Comment: Try now. Should be `With cht.SeriesCollection(1)`.  Code has also been updated and hopefully should update the third chart (the one with 2 series), too. You will need to modify it to refer to the correct chart name.

Comment: well hold that thought> I've downloaded your workbook. Let me play with it for a few minutes. Will update shortly.

Comment: OK. Try the revision. I downloaded your file, created the charts, and use the macro above to update the series data for each of them.

Comment: Okay, what I did was created three blank charts and named them. I changed the name of the third chart in your code. Then I launched the macro and got the same Compile Error at "With cht.SeriesCollection(1)".

Comment: This code doesn't add series to the chart, it just updates existing series.  I can probably modify it to check if series exists, first. Give me a few...

Comment: Okay. Well to explain further the data sheets will be filled with new data every time, trimmed, and then have the charts created. I wont be adding new data to the same report because the report is for one weld. After the charts are made the report will be saved and I will start a new worksheet for the next report. I will just have all of the macros saved on the worksheet template.

Comment: OK. Code's updated now and it will check to see if the chart has any series data, so if you have blank charts, it will add the series data to them.

Comment: Well it does work. Only problem now is that the charts disappear before I can fill them! Ha! I made the blank charts saved the template, opened a new data log and trimmed out the rows I didn't need but as the rows deleted the charts were also delete or were moved to the back of the data so I can't see them. If I create the blank charts after the trim it works perfectly.

Comment: This is why I was trying to get the feature that would create the charts after the trim and place them horizontally under the report information.

Comment: I suppose I could record a macro with a hot key that would create the three blank charts, allowing me to hot key them after the trim but I would still have to drag the chart to the bottom since the reports vary in length.

Comment: @TMC no need for that. see revision #3.  This will create the charts if they do not already exist.

Comment: I am putting the run commands inside of the Sub DeleteRows_0_Step at the end and putting the sub routines inside of your update charts subroutine?

Comment: Try it like here:  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYOWNjM0RPSmkxbEE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: You're going to have to download the file. It should contain `Module1` with all subroutines inside it.

Comment: Okay I will try this code with a different report with a different length and see how it goes.

Comment: It's messing up a little. I will be breaking for lunch but I will be responsive in about an hour.

Comment: This is really about as much time as I can afford to give away. Good luck.

Comment: If it's been helpful, you don't have to "accept" it, but please consider upvoting my answer.

Comment: It has helped. I'm nearly there now just needs a slight tweak. I will upvote because it is a very detailed and helpful answer.

Comment: If anyone can help me further the current code throws a "Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument" at the line 'If IsError(Application.Match("RPM", chts, False)) Then'

Comment: Yep I had fixed that in my answer above, but apparently the revision I didn't update the XLS file.  Try now.  https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1v0s8ldwHRYSEd5N0FGMFRON2s/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Cannot run macro "UpdateCharts". The macro may not be available in this workbook. David I understand that you have probably spent a lot more time than you wanted on this. I understand if you would like to move on. I will try to get others to help me.

Comment: You may have to enable editing, or check your macro security?  Otherwise, maybe try changing `Private Sub ...` to just `Sub ...` for each of the subroutines declared as Private.

Comment: I figured out what it was. I still had the other UpdateCharts module in the list. Deleted and it works fine. Thank you.

Comment: One last thing David, which value do I have to change if I want to make the charts go lower than the last line? A quick answer will be fine.

Comment: `chtTop = ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Top + ws.Cells(lastRow, 1).Height` this sets the position of the first chart, which is then a reference for the other charts. For example, change `lastRow` in both places on this line, to `lastRow + 3` and that will put the charts 3 rows beneat the last row.

Comment: Okay I will try that. The problem is it is erasing the calculated weld time from the DeleteRows_0_Step.

Comment: Well I don't think it's erasing anything, it may be hiding or laying over it, but it's not erasing anything.  You may want to change where it's printing out that value. Currently you're putting it in column B below the last row. I'd probably just put it in cell Z1.

Comment: `Cells(1, 26) = Format(Cells(Var, 2) - Cells(2, 2), "[hh]:mm:ss")`